# Make array in json and pass to all controllers angular

Tags: angularjs

I know I can use angular-translate, but I need something else. I have one json array like this **values.json**

```
{
    "Home": "Home",
    "HOME_MSG": "Welcome to",
    "Show User": "Show User",
    "User name:": "User name:",
    "E-Mail:": "E-Mail:",
    "Edit User": "Edit User"
}
```

What i need something that in every module i can import that json and in view for that module i can simple do this

```
{{Home}}
```

I know this is similar like translate, but problem is that i use webpcak with TS and having problems with translate

Comment: This may help, https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angular-translate

Comment: Otherwise you may consider writing a simple version of angular-translate.

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `angular-translate`, then create a custom **[Angular factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)** where you'll have this object. Then inject the factory in all your controllers and access the needed attributes of the object.

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCcO4vhWrDa9nof9ziwo?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

In you servie create one json, lets say **:**

```
var keys = {
    "Home": "Home",
    "HOME_MSG": "Welcome to",
    "Show User": "Show User",
    "User name:": "User name:",
    "E-Mail:": "E-Mail:",
    "Edit User": "Edit User"
}
```

and when you call the `getLocale` method from the controller to receive the data from the `localeService`, lets say **:**

```
localeService.getLocale('Home');
```

Now your `localeService` must be like this **:**

```
angular.module('app').service('localeService', function() {
    var json = {
      "Home": "Home",
      "HOME_MSG": "Welcome to",
      "Show User": "Show User",
      "User name:": "User name:",
      "E-Mail:": "E-Mail:",
      "Edit User": "Edit User" 
    }

    this.getLocale = function(key) {
        return json.key;
    };
})
```

Comment: Ok, but how to call it in view and not going inside controller

Comment: Ok, but how to show it in view, and put json inisde external file

Comment: You can show it in view using `$scope` object.let's say, `$scope.locale = localeService.getLocale('Home');` then you can use `{{locale}}` in your view.

Comment: Can i pass adding that in controller, i need to do {{Home]} only in the view

Comment: You need to get the service data in a variable then you can bind that variable in the view. You can do like this `$scope.Home = localeService.getLocale('Home');` and then `{{Home}}` in the view

Comment: I need not po pass data in controller, that i can do {{Home}} in every view, just to inject service in global main, is that possible, i can not do $scope.home in every controller

Comment: Yes you can do that inject the service in parent controller and then access it in every child view of that parent.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and make fiddle, that i can accept you answer, txanks a lot

Comment: It will take lot of time to create a fiddle and i am also not sure that in fiddle i will be able to create multiple views. I am sure it will definitely work. Please try to implement it directly in your code.